# Sprite Pixels, and ScreenToWorldPoint

Tags: unity

Just asking a really basic question, but I'm really confused about pixels and positioning.

This is in my update function:

```
//Global variables, GameObject go, SpriteRenderer renderer.
Vector2 worldBoundary = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height/ 2));
Vector3 position = new Vector3(worldBoundary.x, worldBoundary.y, 0); 
var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 4, 4);
var sprite = Sprite.Create(Texture2D.whiteTexture, rect, Vector2.one *0.5f);
renderer.sprite = sprite;
go.transform.position = position;
go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 1f);
```

What I am just trying to understand, based on the code, is that position and camera-relative position are different things. So, assuming my screen is 840px, but my X position is 10.7523.

It's safe to assume that the function just converts the pixel to some position value, isn't it? If I have a square that is 40x40px in the example where scale a 4x4 square by `10.0f`, if I set the `Screen.width / 2 - 20`. What I expect to see is that the square moves 20px, which is equivalent to a square's width, but it's not what I was expecting. Assuming I change to the code below

```
Vector2 worldBoundary = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Screen.width - 20.0f, Screen.height/ 2));
```

[image]

Update:
The Camera settings is in Orthographic, and the sprite.pixelsPerUnit is 100. The Orthographic height is 10.0, and the Orthographic size is 5.

Comment: The mapping between world units, sprite texels, and screen pixels depends on a few extra variables: 1) your Camera settings - orthographic height or perspective field of view, 2) the sprite's pixels per unit setting, which you can find in the import settings inspector when you select the source image in your project window for sprites you've imported. When creating them in code with `Sprite.Create`, you can set the value as an optional parameter, though the documentation is vague about the default value when unset - maybe 100? Check `sprite.pixelsPerUnit` to be sure.

Comment: @DmGregory I didn't use a imported sprite, I used a white texture from Texture2D which is from the library. The camera settings would not be correct for Screen.width, so as to say, if I just use Screen.width the sprite would show half of the square, since the origin point is the center of the sprite. I will check it.

Comment: I know you didn't, that's why I also included instructions for what information to share from the sprite you created with Sprite.Create. Even if you're using Screen.width, we still need your camera settings.

Comment: @DMGregory oh.. my bad, so I checked its 100, and the other is orthographic. Sorry, and thanks for the response.

Comment: Please read carefully. I asked for the orthographic **height** of the camera. The pixel height of the screen will help too, but we can measure that out of the image if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking whether it was orthographic OR perspective. The orthographicSize is 5, so I read that the height is twice of the size? so the height should be 10.0. And the width is actually not fixed, it just follow the width of the game window when I expand other tools it just changes so maybe it doesnt help much for me to give a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pixels per Unit (PPU) value creates a mapping between the texel size of your sprite and the size its corresponding object will be in the game world (at 1x scale).

$$\begin{align}
\text{default world size} &= \frac {\text{texel size}} {\text{PPU}}\\
&= \frac 4 {100}\\
&= 0.04
\end{align}$$

This is then affected by your scaling factor:

$$\begin{align}
\text{scaled world size} &= \text{scale} \times \text{default world size}\\
&= 10 \times 0.04\\
&= 0.4
\end{align}$$

Your camera's orthographic size determines how much of the world it can see vertically. As you noted, the size parameter is half it total height. That height in your world gets mapped to the pixel height of your screen/window/viewport.

$$\begin{align}
\text{pixel size} &= \text{scaled world size} \times \frac {\text{window pixel height}} {2 \times \text{camera size}}\\
&= 0.4 \times \frac {392} {10}\\
&= 15.68
\end{align}$$

That gives us about the 16 pixel width & height we can measure in your 392-pixel-tall example image.

So half your square's width is 8 pixels at this resolution, not 20. That's why the square moves on screen by more than you expect.

If you want to calculate the position that just touches the right edge of the screen, assuming the camera is unrotated and looking straight along the z+ axis, you can do so with...

```cs
static void SnapToRightEdge(Renderer renderer, Camera camera) {
    float rightEdgeOfShape = renderer.bounds.max.x;
  
    float rightEdgeOfScreen = camera.position.x + 
                              camera.orthographicSize * camera.aspect;
                              // half height * width:height ratio = half width

    renderer.transform.Translate(
           rightEdgeOfScreen - rightEdgeOfShape, 
           0,
           0,
           Space.World // Translate in world space, not local space.
    );
}
```

Note that we don't need any pixel calculations here at all, so this will work at any screen resolution. Things get a little more complicated if you need to deal with rotations though, since the bounds structure is a world axis-aligned bounding box.

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand what you mean. So the issue is that my Sprite Object is actually not 40pixels, but 15.86pixels based on my Image. And for me to snap any object to the right edge of the screen I have to get the center to edge of the Shape/Sprite(halfWidth), and the Edge of Screen, and minus the halfWidth away from the edge. Its a little technical that I dont understand some concepts like camera.aspect, Space.World. But is it better or worst to have a way to create a sprite always 1texel size to 1 pixel. that way wouldn't it be easier to navigate the shape around?

Comment: I have only learned abit of javascript game dev, which in that instance I just have a sprite sheet, and set a fixed pixel height/width, and everything would be a 1-1 mapping. eg. I have a 20x20 object in a 400x20 window, so I can fit 20 of said objects. This makes it a lot easier when I want to put an object at the 360px position

Comment: 1 texel = 1 pixel works great, if you only ever want your game to be played on one specific screen resolution. As soon as you need to support 2 screen sizes, now you either need to tolerate your game looking very different on one, or redo all your sprites and code so the numbers work for the new resolution. So I'd strongly recommend getting used to thinking of your game's simulation world space and the output screen's pixel space as separate concepts.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Thanks, snapping right function is not the end it is just an example for me to work on. So thanks for the explanation, and I will think about how to convert this function to accept any x/y position. I appreciate your help to explain the concepts.